# click()/code behind is no longer execute after set InputFile

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I write a page for upload a file to a server.

Before the file is uploading, there should be a question for override the file(if it on the server already)

The check(code behind/Event IndexChange) is set a variable in the client script.
If the user press the "Upload" button a script(confirm_user) check the variable and show a confirm dialog (Override ? Yes/No) and then call a C# function.

It is a ASPX Control running in a IFrame with Masterpage.

My problem:

If I test it without set an input file, it works(break point in code).
But if I select a file for upload the function is not called(press the normal Upload button works fine).

**ASCX File**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="Test_Web.UploadProgress"  Codebehind="UploadProgress.ascx.cs"%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alertify.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default.css" />
<script src="alertify.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
 //hold Check state
 var override = -1;
//Script is working, except Click()
function confirm_user() {
    if (override == 1) {
        if (confirm('Overrride?')) {                document.getElementById('<%=btn_upload_nocheck.ClientID%>').click();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else if (override == 0) {            document.getElementById('<%=btn_upload_nocheck.ClientID%>').click();
        return true;
    }
    return false;

function setoverride(ov) {
    override = ov;

    alertify.alert('Info','Test: '+ ov);
}
//}

</script>

<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up_message">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dd_sendungstitle" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dd_sendungstitle_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>t1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>t2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>t3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>t4</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_progress"></asp:Label>

   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<br/>
<input type="file" id="upUserCtrl" runat="server"/>
<br/>      
<asp:Button ID="btn_upload_nocheck" runat="server"   Text="Upload" Width="101px"  align="center" OnClick="btn_upload_nocheck_Click"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClientClick="return confirm_user();" Text="Upload Script"/>
```

**Code behind File**

```
public partial class UploadProgress: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    ...

    private void ShowMessage(string msg)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<body><script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + msg + "');</script></body>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    }

    protected void btn_upload_nocheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Upload(false);
    }

    private void Upload(bool docheck)
    {

        //Upload File
        int t = _override;
        ...
        ShowMessage("File(" + filename + ") uploaded");
    }


    protected void dd_sendungstitle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do Checking STuff
        if (dd_sendungstitle.SelectedIndex == 0 || dd_sendungstitle.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            _override = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            _override = 1;
        }
        //Set Client Script
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,typeof(string), "javascript", "setoverride(" + _override + ")", true);
    }
}
```